# How can I feature-detect CSS filters?

Tags: css, browser-feature-detection

In some browsers, including Chrome stable, you can do this:

```
h3 {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

And wouldn’t you know it, the h1 will be rendered completely in grayscale. [Everything old is new again](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532853.aspx).

Anyway — does anyone know of any way to feature-detect for this?

I need to be able to apply other styles if the `filter` won’t work.

Comment: You mean different styles inside of `filter`, or `filter` itself?

Comment: @3p3r Oh great, do certain browsers only support some of them?… of course. Well, whatever is necessary to test, I guess.

Comment: I assume, that's the case, because my browser (Chrome 19) supports `filter` but it doesn't support `grayscale`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use CSS' build-in [`@support`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) to conditionally apply styles. Note that the [browser support for `@support` is good but not perfect](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries). This is a nice article explaining how it works with several examples: https://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/feature-detection-with-css

For instance, you can do something like this ([see it live](https://jsfiddle.net/w41j0hfm/)):

```
@supports (filter: grayscale(1)) or (-webkit-filter: grayscale(1)) {
  h3 {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: grayscale(1);
  }
}

@supports not (filter: grayscale(1)) and not not (-webkit-filter: grayscale(1)) {
  h3 {
    color: #808080;
  }
}
```

Comment: More so, there is a JS option alongside it: [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports)

Comment: Times have changed and this is probably now the best answer, so I am changing my accepted answer to this one. That said, I imagine that the number of browsers supporting `@support` but not CSS `filter` must be small... possibly only Opera Mini and some embedded browsers.

Comment: Regarding browser support, every current browser (that is, not dead ones like MSIE) supports `@support` 

Answer (score 19):

So called ***UPDATED*** answer:

As the OP mentioned a good point I'm updating the answer but this does not have anything related or in contradict with my previous answer, this is simply a browser detection.

Alan H. mentioned that IE, prior to its 10th. version, supports `filter` css property but not in the way we all know about it (`CSS3 filter` I meant).

So If we want to feature detect `CSS3 filter`s only, we should go ahead and use a little *browser-detection*. As I mentioned in [my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047206/how-can-i-feature-detect-css-filters#comment15167372_11047247).

Using `documentMode` property, and combining it with our simple feature-detect we can exclude so called false positives in IE.

```
function css3FilterFeatureDetect(enableWebkit) {
    //As I mentioned in my comments, the only render engine which truly supports
    //CSS3 filter is webkit. so here we fill webkit detection arg with its default
    if(enableWebkit === undefined) {
        enableWebkit = false;
    }
    //creating an element dynamically
    el = document.createElement('div');
    //adding filter-blur property to it
    el.style.cssText = (enableWebkit?'-webkit-':'') + 'filter: blur(2px)';
    //checking whether the style is computed or ignored
    //And this is not because I don't understand the !! operator
    //This is because !! is so obscure for learning purposes! :D
    test1 = (el.style.length != 0);
    //checking for false positives of IE
    //I prefer Modernizr's smart method of browser detection
    test2 = (
        document.documentMode === undefined //non-IE browsers, including ancient IEs
        || document.documentMode > 9 //IE compatibility moe
    );
    //combining test results
    return test1 && test2;
}
```

[Original Modernizr source](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/filters.js)

---

```
if(document.body.style.webkitFilter !== undefined)
```

or

```
if(document.body.style.filter !== undefined)
```

***Extra information:***

For just a simple feature detection use my codes above. For a list of supported functions, take a look at here:

- [Filter Effects 1.0](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html)
- [Filter Effects 1.0 functions](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#FilterFunction)

For a live demonstration of `filter`s in Chrome, take a look at here:

- [CSS Filter Effects](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html)

And 2 more resources for you:

- [CSS Filter Effects Landing in WebKit](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit)
- [When can I use CSS Filter Effects?](http://caniuse.com/css-filters)

***As I'm writing this answer, you must use `webkit` vendor prefix to make it to work.***

Comment: Awesome. But I noticed that in Chrome, `.filter` is defined, but does notheing (unlike `.webkitFilter`, which is defined and works). Why do you think that is?

Comment: I don't have any explanations for this, because I know that browser vendor prefixes are for those styles which are in prototype (non standard) phase or ones that are really browser specific.

Comment: @AlanH. [Here](http://caniuse.com/css-filters) remarks that it only works with webkit vendor prefix.

Comment: I guess my concern is that it seems really weird and unreliable that `.filter` is defined but unusable — kind of defeats the point of feature testing if it’s wrong.

Comment: @AlanH. - IE implements a non-standard `filter` CSS property for a different purpose which the new standard replaces.  Maybe Chrome always supported `filter` for compatibility with IE which explains why it's defined, but rest assured it will be replaced with the same thing as `webkitFilter` once standardised.  Unfortunately this does complicate feature detection - how do you detect existence of `filter` in a future-proof way which won't false-positive on IE?

Comment: @AshleysBrain Not sure if my comment here helps or not, but; If you know a specific version of IE (let's say IE8) supports `filter` but in its non-standard way, then why are you looking for feature detection? go with browser detection instead!

Comment: Modernizr now has this feature. They test for `style.filter` and prefixes as mentioned here, and then do a sort-of-browser-detect via IE’s `document.documentMode` property. Here’s the diff for the relevant pull request: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/615/files

Comment: @3p3r I can’t accept w/o  your actual answer including a way to stop false positives in old IEs (and probably including additional prefixes). Address those & I’ll be quite glad to accept.

Comment: @AlanH. Updated it, hope it helps.

Comment: @3p3r Thanks, however this code contains a concatenation error on the line with the ternary operator:
(enableWebkit)?'-webkit-':'' + 'filter: blur(2px)';
should be:
(enableWebkit ?'-webkit-':'') + 'filter: blur(2px)';
Also, if learning purposes is a concern, probably best to prefix el, test1 and test2 with a var.

Answer (score 2):

To build off of @Sepehr's answer, but to modernize it a bit and to remove extra lines:

```
var supportsFilters = (function() {
  var filterEl = document.createElement('div');
  filterEl.style.cssText = 'filter:blur(2px)';
  return filterEl.style.length != 0 && (document.documentMode === undefined || document.documentMode > 9);
})();
```